# what is the difference between sets and fields?

Tags: field-theory

I've read explanations online and I can parrot the explanation that it is numbers taken together with operations that can be performed on them and the rules they follow like associativity, commutative etc. But I don't exactly know what that means or looks like. For example set is a collection of numbers so I can write a set $A = \{1,2,3\}$. If I wanted a field for this set do I write $AF = \{1,2,3,1+2,2+3,1+3,1*2,2*3,1*3\}$?

Please explain this as simply as you can without talking in an abstract manner. Concrete examples would be extremely helpful.

Comment: You would use the same set for a field but you’d need to define the result of addition and multiplication of elements of the set to be an element of the set, and it would have to satisfy certain properties; for example, they could be defined modulo $3$; the field is the set with addition and multiplication

Comment: Please read this [wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Field_(mathematics)) on fields. It explains this with many concrete examples.

Comment: A field is a trio of sets, where the first is a set of objects, the second defines the addition operator, and the third, the multiplication operator.

Comment: The simplest example is the field of rational numbers, which you can think of as the set of all fractions of whole numbers. You can add and multiply fractions just like you learned in school and these operations satisfy all the field axioms. The definition of a field is abstract, because its purpose is to be an abstraction of useful properties that the rational numbers have: a field is something that we can do calculations with about as nicely as we can do with rational numbers.

Comment: Re: your last paragraph, this is a somewhat abstract subject to begin with - it's impossible to completely avoid talking abstractly *(and it would be unhelpful to do so, ultimately: the issue really is about how the abstraction works)*.

Comment: @DonThousand How do the addition and multiplication operators get viewed as sets? I suppose I can imagine viewing them as collections of triples, but that seems like an awkward and not very helpful way to think of them.

Comment: @MorganRodgers You can see them as functions $+,\cdot: X\times X\to X$. A function $f$ can be viewed as a set of ordered pairs $(a,b)$ such that $f(a)=b$. An ordered pair $(a,b)$ then can be seen as the set $\{\{a\},\{a,b\}\}$. So it all reduces to being sets built from the elements of $X$. E.g. the operator $+:\Bbb R\times\Bbb R\to\Bbb R$ could be represented as a set containing pairs such as $((2,3),5)$, since $+(2,3)=5$, usually written as $2+3=5$.

Comment: @VineetKaushik - A set is not necessarily composed of numbers. For example, $A=\{\text{red},\text{green},\text{blue}\}$ is a set, but there is no obvious way to add or multiply colours. We could make $A$ into a field by deciding how to add and multiply.

Comment: @Morgan My comment was partially directed towards the OP as well, hence the detailed description of how to see functions as sets. Perhaps not very helpful in terms of understanding what a field is, but it is helpful to realise how versatile and useful sets are, and that a field can be represented by a triple of sets that satisfy some properties. Especially considering the OP is confused about how to write a field as a set.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think it's helpful to think in terms of *information*. If I have a set and I want to tell you what it is, I just have to tell you its elements; then you completely understand what the set is. With a field, however, I need to do more than just tell you what the elements of the field are - I *also* have to tell you how they add and multiply.

For example, consider a two-element set $\{a,b\}$. There are **two distinct** fields which use this as their underlying set: we could have $a$ play the role of $0$ and $b$ play the role of $1$, or $a$ play the role of $1$ and $b$ play the role of $0$. The point is:

> If I just tell you "My field's domain is $\{a,b\}$," I haven't actually told you all there is to know about my field.

---

You should really think of a field as a **tuple**: a field consists of

- a set $F$,
- two distinct elements $\underline{0},\underline{1}$ of $F$ *(so in particular $F$ has to have at least $2$ elements)*, and
- two binary operations $\oplus,\otimes$ on $F$

such that [various properties]. The set $F$ on its own doesn't tell us too much; to understand the field we need to understand  the *whole tuple* $$\langle F, \underline{0}, \underline{1},\oplus,\otimes\rangle.$$

Comment: Note that fields have a rather special property which ameliorates the situation above to a certain extent: any two finite fields with the same cardinality are isomorphic, so in some sense once I know the domain - as long as it's finite! - I *do* know all the "structural information" about the field. But this should be ignored for now; in particular, it's very special to finite fields *(it fails for infinite fields or for finite rings, for example)* and your question is more generally relevant to basically all types of mathematical structures.